# Let $x_n$ be an orthonormal sequence in $H$ and let $T$ be a continuous operator s.t $T(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ prove it is a unique

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x_n$ be an orthonormal sequence in a hilbert space $H$ and let $T$ be a continuous operators s.t $T(x_n)=x_{n+1}$ prove that there is a unique such $T$ and find $T^*$.

I am not sure but I think this problem is not correct. I think we need $x_n$ is an orthonormal basis, but i might be wrong. My proof in the case when $x_n$ is an orthonormal basis:

Let $x \in H$, then $x=\sum(x,x_n)x_n$ and so $T(x)=\sum(x,x_n)x_{n+1}$ using continuity. Thus $T$ is completely determined by its action on the orthonormal basis. So $T$ is unique. If $x_n$ is not an orthonormal basis, all we get is that $T$ is determined on the space generated by $x_n$. I am not sure how that also determines what $T$ does on its orthogonal complement. Any hints would be appriciated, or perhaps letting me know the problem is incorrectly stated.

I also found that in this case $T^*=\sum(x_{n+1},x)x_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously false. On $\mathbb R^{2}$, $T(1,0)=(0,1)$ does not determine $T$ uniquely. Take, for example, $T(x,y)=(cy,x)$ where $c$ is arbitrary. I am looking at the orthonormal set $\{(1,0)\}$.

$T$ is unique if $(x_n)$ is an orthonormal basis and in this case your computation of $T^{*}$ is correct.